# Cannot remove modal dialog with removeModal()

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
modalDialog(
    title = "Clicking below to hide the modal does not work",
    footer = actionButton("ready", "OK")
)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$ready, {
    removeModal(session)
  })
}
```

This does not give me any errors, it just does not work. My screen turns gray and the modal stays, unresponsive. Meanwhile, if I delete my custom button and use the default "Dismiss", then it works. I've tried with assigning ID and removing session argument, as well as many other things. I **need** the modal to be in UI (since package functions that I use do not work inside server) and I **need** observe for the "ok" button to pass arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sure why that is, try putting it into the `server.R`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  showModal(
    modalDialog(
    title = "Clicking below to hide the modal does not work",
    footer = actionButton("ready", "OK")
  ))
  
  observeEvent(input$ready, {
    removeModal()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It worked now. Weird... if I have my app launched in browser and then edit something, save and run it again, does it update the code, or does it run the code the way it was when I first launched it? Because if it's the latter then that's what would explain me trying this and not getting any results...